# Bash is removing commands in while?

Tags: bash, replace

I really dont understand why this is happening, bash seems to remove commands while running in a `while` loop.
I have the following script:

```
adb shell ls /foo/bar | while read file 
do
    folder="/foo/bar/$file"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    adb pull $folder download
done
```

when i run the command seperatly, it works great. But wen i run it like this, i get the following output:

```
' does not existfoo/bar/filesdfsdf.sdf
```

for every file in /foo/bar.

SO i tried to give me the command back as string, i changed to `echo "adb pull $folder download"` and got the following output:

```
 download/foo/bar/fileasdfs.sdf
```

for each line. It seems that bash does something with the string and replaces some stuff here...
If i use `'`, so no bash replacement would occur, i get the correct output.

whats happening here?

EDIT: I figured out that not `while` is directly broken, its the `adb shell` command what echoes a CRLF on every line end. if i use

```
adb shell ls /foo/bar | tr -d '\015' | while read file 
do
    folder="/foo/bar/$file"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    adb pull $folder download
done
```

it works!
But why is bash so allergic to CRLF? And why its deletes comnmands?

Comment: try quoting your folder var, i.e. `echo  adb pull "$folder" download`. Good idea to use `echo` until you're getting the results you want!. Good luck.

Comment: ok woot lol, i figured out that adb uses CRLF to echo a new line... while goes crazy when i do so and stripes out commands oO. i added a `| tr -d '\015'` to remove all CR from adb shell output. Why does while does not allow CR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "Why does while not allow CR?". The correct question is "What does read do with CR?". Unless stating otherwise, `read` uses CR for parameter splitting. Look in your bash-manual for the variable `IFS`, and have a look at the `-d` option to read.

Example:

```
bos:$ echo foo bar gazonk | while read x ; do echo $x ; done
foo bar gazonk
```

Here, the CR acts as (default) delimiter for `read`. Now, say you want to split the read at every word, then you would use `-d " "` (setting SPC as delimiter):

```
$ echo foo bar gazonk hello 123 | while read -d " " x ; do echo $x ; done
foo
bar
gazonk
hello
```

The backside here is that the last parameter (123) is not output because it does not end with a delimiter. Think of the delimiter as grabbing everything LEFT of it, up to but not including the next delimiter. Since "123" does not end with a delimiter, the last delimiter is between "hello" and "123", and - thus - what's grabbed is "hello" because it has a delimiter to left and to right of it.