# How do I adb pull ALL files of a folder present in SD Card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have a folder in my SD Card as:
`/mnt/sdcard/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/*.jpg`

The name of Folder1 and Folder2 remains constant and inside Folder2 I have Folder3, 4, 5 and so on..
I want to pull all the jpeg files rather than all files (there are more) using adb to my current directory on the computer..

Every folder has **different number** of jpeg files and other files and I tried using this:

```
adb pull mnt/sdcard/Folder1/Folder2/Folder/*.jpg .
```

But it didn't work..
So uhmm how do I adb pull all files present in any folder of SD Card with a single command (single command because each folder has different number of files)

Comment: Are you in Linux or Windows? This can we solved with a simple script?

Comment: Hmm i have the Android Developement Stuff installed on both: Win7 as well as Ubuntu .. if there is solution for both then well and good..!
But in reality i need it only for Ubuntu (installed as a VM) .. so uhmm yeah im on Ubuntu..

Comment: can you please mark a correct answer for this question?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

### Single File/Folder using `pull`:

```
adb pull "/sdcard/Folder1"
```

Output:

```
adb pull "/sdcard/Folder1"
pull: building file list...
pull: /sdcard/Folder1/image1.jpg -> ./image1.jpg
pull: /sdcard/Folder1/image2.jpg -> ./image2.jpg
pull: /sdcard/Folder1/image3.jpg -> ./image3.jpg
3 files pulled. 0 files skipped.
```

### Specific Files/Folders using `find` from `BusyBox`:

```
adb shell find "/sdcard/Folder1" -iname "*.jpg" | tr -d '\015' | while read line; do adb pull "$line"; done;
```

Here is an explanation:

```
adb shell find "/sdcard/Folder1" - use the find command, use the top folder
-iname "*.jpg"                   - filter the output to only *.jpg files
|                                - passes data(output) from one command to another
tr -d '\015'                     - explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664086/bash-is-removing-commands-in-while
while read line;                 - while loop to read input of previous commands
do adb pull "$line"; done;         - pull the files into the current running directory, finish. The quotation marks around $line are required to work with filenames containing spaces.
```

The scripts will start in the top folder and recursively go down and find all the "*.jpg" files and pull them from your phone to the current directory.

Comment: `adb pull /sdcard` to pull all!

Comment: @IanVaughan that is a command I use often and works for me but I do wish there was a way to pull everything off the sd card but exclude one of the sub paths

Comment: I wonder if Android has `tar`?  A simple tarpipe over ADB would allow very fine-grained pulling of files, metadata, but with exclusions.  If gzip/bzip2 is also on there, then a compressed tarpipe would be available :)

Comment: For _modern_ versions of `adb` you can just specify the directory and the tool will recursivly pull everything for you

Comment: @mark-k-cowan adb backup with shared (sdcard) is plenty of bugs.

Comment: If you need more customization of the pull operation, you can use a Python script that lists the folders/files then executes each one's transfer independently -- meaning you can add custom logic for deciding which ones to proceed with. I use `adb-sync` for this (with source changes/customizations): https://stackoverflow.com/a/57138127/2441655

Comment: `adb pull -a -p /sdcard` to pull all, show progress and **preserve timestamp**!

Comment: It seems like the latest version `31.0.3 (August 2021)` doesn't require `-p` switch to show progress. I don't know since when. But it will always show on default at the moment.

Comment: how can we push all folders from current directory in windows to android just like this pull command I have tried with batch scriting with `for /r %i in (*) do adb push %i storage/emulated/0` and creating zip but I am looking for more easy solution just like this pull one @JaredBurrows

Comment: Only double slash at the beginning of the path worked for me, like this: `"//sdcard/..."`

Answer (score 73):

Directory pull is available on new android tools.
( I don't know from which version it was added, but its working on latest ADT 21.1 )

```
adb pull /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots
pull: building file list...
pull: /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/090313-110415.jpg -> ./090313-110415.jpg
pull: /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/090313-110412.jpg -> ./090313-110412.jpg
pull: /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/090313-110408.jpg -> ./090313-110408.jpg
pull: /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/090313-110406.jpg -> ./090313-110406.jpg
pull: /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/090313-110404.jpg -> ./090313-110404.jpg
5 files pulled. 0 files skipped.
61 KB/s (338736 bytes in 5.409s)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it only pulled some directories. Not sure what its criteria was.

Comment: If you want to pull a folder owned by _root_, start an `adb` root session (using `$ adb root`).

Comment: run the command as root just like @MasterAM said!
worked without a problem! cheers!

Comment: @acjay Empty folders are omitted. This is also true of recursive folders that are ultimately empty. E.g. `/sdcard/folder1/folder2` will result in `folder1` being omitted if `folder2` is empty and there are no other files under `folder1`.

Answer (score 48):

Please try with just giving the path from where you want to pull the files
I just got the files from sdcard like

`adb pull sdcard/`

do NOT give `*` like to broaden the search or to filter out.
ex: `adb pull sdcard/*.txt` --> this is invalid.

just give `adb pull sdcard/`

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution.  It's semantically better and preserves the directory structure too.

Comment: Note that the trailing `/` __does__ mater.

Comment: I did not need trailing slash with adb version 1.0.40

Answer (score 6):

Yep, just use the trailing slash to recursively pull the directory.  Works for me with Nexus 5 and current version of adb (March 2014).

Comment: I did not need trailing slash with adb version 1.0.40

Comment: I needed the trailing slash on Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32 running Android Q on Google Pixel XL.

Answer (score 3):

On Android 6 with ADB version 1.0.32, you have to put / behind the folder you want to copy. E.g `adb pull "/sdcard/".`

Comment: I did not need trailing slash with adb version 1.0.40

Comment: The slash AND the dot is what did it for me, otherwise the folder is copied not just the content.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pull a directory with restricted access from a rooted device you need to restart adb as root: type `adb root` before pull. Otherwise you'll get an error saying `remote object '/data/data/xxx.example.app' does not exist`

Comment: Don't forget to set ADB root access in developer actions otherwise you'll get this error `ADB Root access is disabled by system setting - enable in Settings -> System -> Developer options`

Answer (score 1):

if your using jellybean just start cmd, type adb devices to make sure your readable, type adb pull sdcard/ sdcard_(the date or extra) <---this file needs to be made in adb directory beforehand. PROFIT!

In other versions type adb pull mnt/sdcard/ sdcard_(the date or extra)

Remember to make file or your either gonna have a mess or it wont work.