# Allure-Kotlin does not create allure-results in Espresso tests

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-espresso, allure

I tried step by step the instructions from [Allure-Kotlin](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-kotlin) for android tests. But after finishing my tests when I run(on Pixel_4_API_29):

`adb pull /sdcard/allure-results` This message is shown:

> adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/sdcard/allure-results': No such file or directory

This is a [sample repo](https://github.com/jose-83/BasicSample) I created to show what I did exactly.

More info: I run tests using `./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest`, tests are run with `@RunWith(AllureAndroidJUnit4.class)`, I already added `allure.prperties` file to androidTest resources as well as listeners to `META-INF.services`. Also, I updated Kotlin version to 1.4.21 and Gradle to 6.7.1 to be matched with allure-kotlin 2.2.5. I also already made sure of required permission to access to `/sdcard` folder on emulator.

I really appreciate any helpful answer and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have looked at your code. It looks like you have a problem in AndroidManifest.xml.
Please, check [pr](https://github.com/jose-83/BasicSample/pull/1)

We have prepared several [examples](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-kotlin/tree/master/samples/junit4-android). Thus you are able to have a look and touch allure-kotlin.

Comment: Awesome! It works very well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @victor Doesn't work on Android 12. Can you please check

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to do `adb pull /sdcard` to pull everything and then see if there is an issue with the sdcard folder?

Also, another issue could be syntax error `adb pull "/sdcard/allure-results/"`

Beside this, there is a lot of question answered on topic of the posted error, such as: [How do I adb pull ALL files of a folder present in SD Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050925/how-do-i-adb-pull-all-files-of-a-folder-present-in-sd-card)

I hope that something from this helps! :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I mentioned in the question, there is no problem in accessing sdcard folder on emulator/device. There was some problem with Allure settings that has been fixed by suggestion from the other answer.