# Copy folder from /data/data/ with adb

Tags: android, powershell, adb

how can I copy the folder from /data/data to my pc using adb?

I tried this and this copy only 1 file but I want to copy the whole folder

```
adb -d shell "run-as com.example.test cat /data/data/com.example.test/databases/data.db" > data.db
```

Comment: Have you tried adb pull? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050925/how-do-i-adb-pull-all-files-of-a-folder-present-in-sd-card

Comment: I suppose it can be achieved with `$ adb pull`.

Comment: You can use [Android Studio's Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) for accessing the files in a graphical way. Alternatively if you want to capture all files you can create a tar archive (instead of `cat`) : `tar cv  /data/data/com.example.test/`.